# trying to access number variable outside the function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, global-variables

Creating Stars rating system and I want to access the rating number and perform an action based on that. How can I access the number variable outside my click function?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".li").mouseover(function () {
                var current = $(this);
                $(".li").each(function (index) {
                    $(this).addClass("hovered-stars");
                    if (index == current.index()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            })
            $(".li").mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("hovered-stars");
            })
            $(".li").click(function () {
                $(".li").removeClass("clicked");
                $(".hovered-stars").addClass("clicked");
                var number = $(".clicked").length;
                $("#message").html("You rated " + number + " Stars");
            })
            console.log(number);
        })
```

Currently cannot print number variable outside click event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare  the number variable outside the click function and then re-assign the value inside click function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var number=0;
        $(".li").mouseover(function () {
            var current = $(this);
            $(".li").each(function (index) {
                $(this).addClass("hovered-stars");
                if (index == current.index()) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        })
        $(".li").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hovered-stars");
        })
        $(".li").click(function () {
            $(".li").removeClass("clicked");
            $(".hovered-stars").addClass("clicked");
            number = $(".clicked").length;
            $("#message").html("You rated " + number + " Stars");
        })
        console.log(number);
    })
```

Comment: Yes, But it is still not printing the value outside the click listener. Printing 0 in the console.

Comment: then there may be some problem with the logic you have written. there is no problem in accessing the variable